# Getting the current locale with ICU

Tags: c, locale, icu

Many ICU functions take a char * representing the locale as a parameter.  If I statically set this to "ko_KR", for example, then it does indeed operate in a locale-sensitive manner.

However, I want to determine the current locale based on system settings for time formatting.  As far as I understand, most systems have a locale setting for displaying numbers, time, money, etc and these could all vary.  Any ideas about how to do this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uloc_getDefault() will return the overall default locale that ICU detected from the underlying system. The categories you mentioned don't cleanly map across all operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

Seems this can be done with the locale.h functions

```
char * loc;
loc = setlocale(LC_TIME, "");
```